# How to select item using Tab key with JQuery's combobox

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, combobox, autocomplete

I'm using JQuery's [combobox](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox) example code along with a remote datasource. It works great but I'd like to autoselect an option when I hit the tab key. For instance, if I start typing and there's only one option available I'd like to hit the tab key and have it autoselect the only available option.

Any ideas on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try binding the next event to the textbox:

```
input.keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.TAB) {
        var menu = input.data("autocomplete").menu;
        menu.activate($.Event({ type: "mouseenter" }), menu.element.children().first());
        menu.select(e);
    }
});
```